# What do I need to do with this try catch so it won't throw up a code?

Tags: java, try-catch

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class L4a {



public static void main(String[] args) {
  File f = new File("circles.in");
  Scanner input = null;
  try {
      input = new Scanner(f);
  }
  
  catch (FileNotFoundException e)
  {
  }
  
  int sum = 0;
  int num = input.nextInt();
  
  while (input.hasNext())
  {
      sum = sum + num;
      num = input.nextInt();
  }     System.out.println("Sum of all numbers = " + sum);

}
```

}

I have this code and it keep throwing up an error and I just can't seem to figure out what is wrong. I tried fixing it and putting the while loop in between the try catch but still could not figure it out.

Comment: What is the error? Please share the exact error message and stack trace.

Comment: What you are getting is a `NullPointerException`. Try to read about it and guess what could be null in your code and how you can handle it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the exact directory for circles.in, such as

> "C:\\Users\\User...\\circles.in"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).